# Importerror: DLL load failed while importing ie_api

Tags: python, openvino

I'm using python==3.8 anaconda environment. I'm getting the error DLL load failed while importing ie_api.

Dose python 3.8 support OpenVino?

Answer (score 0):

OpenVINO toolkit supports Python 3.6-3.9 (64-bit) version, as mentioned in the software [System Requirements](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html).

The error is due to OpenVINO environment not being configured. If you installed OpenVINO from the installer, you need to call the `Setupvars.bat` script to initialize the OpenVINO environment. The script can be found in `openvino/bin` directory.

For OpenVINO installed from PyPi repository, you need to add your `PYTHON PATH` into your `environment variables.` In your case, add path of your Anaconda installation into the `environment variables` as below:

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. while running with CMD and Terminal I can able to run the code. Then also if add this line able to run with pycharm. Refer to the link (https://chowdera.com/2022/03/202203271333550147.html )

Comment: What is your OpenVINO version and how did you install it? For installation from OpenVINO installer, please configure the environment before you can compile and run OpenVINO™ applications.

Comment: I'm using openvino_2021.4.582. I installed it by using the openvino toolkit 2021.4.

Comment: Please reinstall your OpenVINO_2021.4. During installation, make sure you click the option Add Python 3.x to PATH to add Python to your PATH environment variable. To configure the environment, open the Command Prompt, and run the setupvars.bat batch file to temporarily set your environment variables: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\bin\setupvars.bat"